# Android AcousticEchoCanceler not cancelling audio

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to use 'AcousticEchoCanceler' on an app of mine to record my voice while an audio file is playing through the speaker.  I am figuring that the audio playing through my speaker would be like someone else talking to me through VOIP.  The main point is that I would like to recognize when someone is talking through the microphone while an audio file is being played over the speaker.

I made a simple test app that records your voice while you're pressing a button, then immediately plays it back.  The test I'm running is that while the audio is being played back through the speaker, I press the button again and record a second time.  This second audio recording "should" be only my voice of the second recording.

```
private Button recordButton;
private TextView recordText;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private static String mFileName = null;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
public AcousticEchoCanceler aec;
//public int recordingNum = 0;
public AudioManager mAudioManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set audio mode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    recordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
    recordText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recordText);

    recordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                recordingStart();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                recordingStop();
                playingStart();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void recordingStart() {
    recordText.setText("RECORDING");
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("*******", "prepare() failed");
    }
    mRecorder.start();
}

private void recordingStop() {
    recordText.setText("RECORDING STOPPED");
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}

private void playingStart() {
    recordText.setText("PLAYING");
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                playingStop();
            }
        });
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
        //Use AcousticEchoCanceler during the playing?
        aec.create(mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("*******", "prepare() failed");
    }
}

private void playingStop() {
    recordText.setText("WAITING");
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
}

public MainActivity() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest1.3gp";
}
```

I may not be using the AEC correctly, but I'm not sure where to go from here.